# Given 3 line equations, find incenter(center of the inscribed circle) of the triangle formed

Tags: geometry, analysis

Let $4x -y+2=0, x-4y-8=0, x+4y-8=0$ make a triangle. Find the $(x,y)$ coordinates of the triangle's incenter(center of the inscribed circle).

I know that the intersection of the bisectors make the triangle's incenter. I have also tried to calculate each of the triangle's vertices, but I can't make it any further.

Comment: Hint: the gradient of the angle bisector of two lines $L_1, L_2$ is the mean of the gradients of $L_1$ and $L_2$.

Comment: Hint: the $x$ axis is line bissector of $L_2$ and $L_3$, thus...

Comment: @JoshChen: so the slope of the line $y=x$ is the average between $0$ and $+\infty$?

Comment: Not only two sides are symmetric with respect to the $x$-axis, but the given triangle is also a right triangle.

Comment: @Jack D'oh! Replace "gradient" with "angle with the $x$-axis". Of course then the hint becomes not as useful.

Comment: Note that the normals in the equations of the three lines have equal length, so finding the angle bisectors is very simple.